# Signpost OAuth on Android: how to re-create the Consumer between two succesive runs?

Tags: android, oauth, signpost

I'm succesfully using Signpost to authorize calls to protected resources in a Google account via OAuth.

However it seems a bit weird that the user has to go each and every time through Google and grant access. Is there a way of serializing the Consumer and recreating it so that re-authorization is not needed? I've tried keeping the tokens, secret and verifier in the shared preferences and setting them in the Consumer but I receive a OAuthExpectationFailedException.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Once you've received the access token, you can store it in your apps preferences like this :

```
provider.retrieveAccessToken(consumer, oauth_verifier);

final Editor edit = prefs.edit();
edit.putString(OAuth.OAUTH_TOKEN, consumer.getToken());
edit.putString(OAuth.OAUTH_TOKEN_SECRET, consumer.getTokenSecret());
edit.commit();
```

Afterwards, you can always re-create the consumer like this :

```
private OAuthConsumer getConsumer(SharedPreferences prefs) {
    String token = prefs.getString(OAuth.OAUTH_TOKEN, "");
    String secret = prefs.getString(OAuth.OAUTH_TOKEN_SECRET, "");
    OAuthConsumer consumer = new CommonsHttpOAuthConsumer(Constants.CONSUMER_KEY, Constants.CONSUMER_SECRET);
    consumer.setTokenWithSecret(token, secret);
    return consumer;
}
```

Once you've got the consumer, you can make API calls and the consumer will sign them.

```
DefaultHttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
HttpGet request = new HttpGet(url);
consumer.sign(request);
HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(request);
```

According to the [signpost docs](http://code.google.com/p/oauth-signpost/) :

*Signpost objects are very lightweight, so **you are adviced to create an OAuthConsumer and OAuthProvider for every thread in your application that must send signed HTTP requests**. Both objects are also serializable, so you can persist and restore them later.*